# Add end of one list to end of another list in Python - Leetcode

Tags: python, list, merge

I've successfully solved question #88 on Leetcode, found here: https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-sorted-array/

The problem asks us to merge list nums2 into list nums1 in-place in ascending order.

I'm trying to simplify my code (below). I've commented out the last part of code from my original solution (that worked correctly). Just above this I've added an "if c2 < n" statement, in an attempt to do everything in the commented code more simply. I am getting incorrect output, and for the life of me I can't figure out why it's not working. I'm just trying to replace the end of list nums1 with the end of list nums2.

The incorrect output from my new solution:

```
[2,5,2,3,0,0,0]
```

The correct output is:

```
[1,2,2,3,5,6]
```

For input:

nums1 = [1,2,3,0,0,0], m = 3, nums2 = [2,5,6], n = 3, where m and n are the lengths of nums1 and nums2, respectively.

```
class Solution:
    def merge(self, nums1: List[int], m: int, nums2: List[int], n: int) -> None:

        if not nums2:
            return
        c1 = 0
        c2 = 0
        while m > c1 and n > c2:
            if nums2[c2] <= nums1[c1]:
                nums1.insert(c1, nums2[c2])
                c2 += 1
                c1 += 1
                m += 1
            else:
                c1 += 1

        if c2 == n:
            del nums1[m:]
            return

    #  New code to add end of nums2 to end of nums1
        if c2 < n:
            nums1[:n-c2] = nums2[:n-c2]

    #   Old code to add end of nums2 to end of nums1
    #    while c2 < n:
    #        nums1[c1] = nums2[c2]
    #        c2 += 1
    #        c1 += 1

    #   delete trailing 0s
    #    del nums1[c1:]
```

Sorry if my code is ugly, I am new to programming.

Comment: What should the output be if the input is: `nums1 = [1,2,3,0,0,0], m = 3, nums2 = [2,5], n = 2`

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution with [`heapq.merge`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge):

```
from heapq import merge

class Solution:
    def merge(self, nums1: List[int], m: int, nums2: List[int], n: int) -> None:        
        nums1[:] = merge(nums1[:m], nums2)
```

The result (screenshot from Leetcode):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import numpy as np

nums1 = [1,2,3,0,0,0]
m = 3
nums2 = [2,5,6]
n = 3

print("Input: ",nums1,nums2)

nums1 = nums1[:m]
nums2 = nums2[:n]

print("Step 1: ", nums1, nums2)
step2 = np.concatenate((nums1, nums2))

print("Step 2:", step2)
step3 = np.sort(step2)

print("Step3: ", step3)
```

output is:

```
Input:  [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0] [2, 5, 6]
Step 1:  [1, 2, 3] [2, 5, 6]
Step 2: [1 2 3 2 5 6]
Step3:  [1 2 2 3 5 6]
```